# API to find out how many executors are running my Spark jobs?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm writing code that captures statistics from Spark runs and stores the results in XML files. I'd like to capture, ideally with the REST API, information about the number of executors and the number and size of the Data Frames that were created. Is there an easy way to do this? What are the API calls?

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the number of executors is independent of the number of partitions of your dataframe. You set the number of executors when creating *SparkConf()* object.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

To retrieve the number of executors from code, it depends of the API you use. For python, this is not currently implemented. For Scala, you can. Here is a good stack post :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660907/how-to-get-the-number-of-workersexecutors-in-pyspark

Number of partitions refers to the number of parts your dataframe is composed of. With pyspark API, you can get it by transform your dataframe to a rdd and then use method *.getNumPartitions()* :

```
num_partitions = df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've written code to go in through the HTTP JSON API. I'm still not entirely clear on the difference between the number of partitions and the number of executors.

Comment: Executors are JVM with assigned ressources (CPU, memory, cores..) you create every time you instanciate a SparkContext object. Executors are entities that complete the tasks associated with your spark job.

Partitions refers to the number of blocks that compose your rdd/dataframe. If you have a dataframe with 100k rows and 10 partitions, you can expect each partition to be 10k rows of your dataframe.

When executing a task, each executor is capable of handling one or more partitions at the same time given the ressources you have allocated.

Comment: Num of partition does not give exact number of executors. Number of executor depends on spark configuration and mode[yarn, mesos, standalone] another case, If RDD have more partition and executors are very less, than one executor can run on multiple partitions.

Comment: one more thing if dyanmic resource [executor] configuration enable, then irrespective of partition, n number of executor allocated based on amount execution time needed [num of pending tasks and partitions remains for compuation]